# Refunding an in-app purchase doesn't void it

Tags: java, android

I have multiple test accounts for in-app purchases in an android app. When an account makes a purchase that's it, there's no reversing it. I click refund in the play console and wait many days, I then uninstall the app, click Clear Data on the play store, and install the app again but the purchase remains valid. I mean the money gets refunded but the user still has the benefits of the purchase.

How do you prevent this? Also would be nice if I could detect a voided purchase in the app code, without uninstalling then reinstalling the app and without clearing the data of the Play Store.

Am using the google billing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Play [Voided Purchases API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.voidedpurchases/list) provides a list of orders that are associated with purchases that a user has voided. You can use information from this list to implement a revocation system that prevents the user from accessing products from those orders.

This API applies to one-time in-app orders and App Subscriptions.

Please note that Play doesn't revoke anything from the user, it's all up to the developer to decide whether and what to revoke.